# Function notation/mapping for this type of functions?

Tags: programming-languages, notation, mathematical-foundations, mathematical-analysis

In short, what is the proper function notation/mapping for this type of functions?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)#In_computer_science) regarding maps:

> In the communities surrounding programming languages that treat functions as first-class citizens, a map is often referred to as the binary higher-order function that takes a function $f$ and a list $[v_0, v_1, \dots, v_n]$ as arguments and returns $[f(v_0), f(v_1), ..., f(v_n)]$ (where $n \geq 0$).

In mathematics we use the function and mapping notation
\begin{align}
f&:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n \tag 1   \\
x&\mapsto (f_1(x), \dots, f_n(x)) \tag 2
\end{align}
Where $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ and we often write
$$
f(x_1,\dots, x_n)=(
f_1(x_1,\dots, x_n),
\dots, 
f_n(x_1,\dots, x_n)
)
\tag 3
$$

**Question:**

According Wikipedia we have the variable $v=(v_0,\dots, v_n)$ and a function of the form
\begin{align}
f(v_0,\dots, v_n)=
(f(v_1), f(v_2), \dots, f(v_n))
\tag 4
\end{align}
But this form doesn't correlate with the notation in $(1)-(3)$. What is the proper function/mapping notation for $(4)$?

Comment: What is the question precisely? Whether there is a standard mathematical notation for what computer scientists call `map`?

Comment: The (computer science) mapping of a function on the components of a tuple corresponds to the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) (Cartesian power in this case) of $f$ with itself. If you have, for example $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then you have $\prod_{i=1}^{n}f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined as $(\prod_{i=1}^{n}f)(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)=(f(v_1),f(v_2),...,f(v_n))$. This notation is not used enough to use it without explicitly defining it.

Comment: For example, the Wikipedia article is denoting it as $\langle f,f,...,f\rangle$, which is also not widely used either.

Comment: @plop Can you explain your notation further? You have the product symbol over $i$ but no $i$ in your function, is it a typo? Do you mean $\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(v_i)=(f(v_1),f(v_2),...,f(v_n))$?

Comment: There is no missing $i$. If the $i$ is not in the factor, is because the factor is independent of $i$ and it is being multiplied (Cartesian product) with itself $n$ times.

Comment: @plop My bad, I mixed up the product symbol and the Cartesian power used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_power). Does it mean $(\prod_{i=1}^{n}f)(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$ is a short for $(f\times f \times \dots \times f)(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$, where $\times$ is the Cartesian product $n$ times?

Comment: Yes. Maybe in some books you could find also the notation $f^{\times n}$.